# Windows update LOGGING is affecting my internet connection - what can I do?

Tags: windows-10, networking, internet, logging

I have Comodo installed on my system and make use of it's HIPS system. I have removed every vendor from the 'trusted vendors' list so it's treats Microsoft as 'untrusted' and notifies me every time MS attempts to make changes to my system, asking me if I want to allow or prevent the attempts.

To be clear - this has nothing to do with the normal Windows Update process. I go to settings and check the update page and it says "you're up to date" but regardless, every couple of days the 'system' process attempts to creates a new log file in C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsUpdate and every time I allow this my internet connection becomes non-functional.

I remain connected to the internet - no issues are reported by windows at all. I also have a bandwidth monitor so I can see that no data is being transferred - the connection is NOT being overloaded. If I try to troubleshoot the network no problems can ever be found. It appears as though I am still connected and that my speeds are normal however neither my torrents, nor my browsers will work until perhaps 30 mins after that log has been written.

I'm not interested in a solution so much as I'm interested in finding out what's going on here. The 'solution' is to disallow the system process from writing the log but I want to know ... how can the writing of these logs be affecting my internet connection like this? It remains up and running, no data is being transferred yet I can't access sites via browser or peers via a torrent client. I know it's the writing of these logs - every time I allow one to be written the problem re-emerges.

Insight into what's going on here will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So what is in the log?

Comment: As far as I can tell it's general windows update information. They are .etl files - here's a small copy/paste from one of them ...

    WUTraceLogging               Shared Info I n i t i a l i z e S u s       ø À   0   ü0  ß.Ñ?  ozÄGNEŒ\èhÖ7äØ                                          WUTraceLogging                IdleTimer Info      N o n - A o A c   m a c h i n e .     A o a c   o p e r a t i o n s   w i l l   b e   i g n o r e d .   Ì À   0   ü0  <.Ñ?  ozÄGNEŒ\èhÖ7äØ